# Cassandra adding new datacenter in runing cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra dse 4.7, 3 node running cluster with one data center, now we are planning to add another data center with 3 nodes. I followed the steps mentioned in:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html.
We have around 20GB of data on each node (total : 60GB).

The problem is when I run:

```
nodetool rebuild --old_datacenter_name on one of new node
```

it is very slow to sync data from cluster. I have already increased `getstreamthroughput` and `getcompactionthroughput` but still no luck.

Are there any other parameters I could tune for faster synchronisation of the data to a newly added node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it is slow and crashed my node during rebuild ,
  in my case the problem is secondary index , I created secondary index on each table  and during rebuild it is more time consuming and eating all heap memory , due to this my node crashed many times .

I just delete secondary index and tried it is working fine.
after rebuild I created secondary index again .